# How to fix - TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape questions from a [web forum](https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/browse?utf8=%E2%9C%93&flow_state=published&search=&order=created_at.desc)  with `python` and `BeautifulSoup` library.

Here is how im trying to get the questions:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/browse?utf8=%E2%9C%93&flow_state=published&search=&order=created_at.desc"
req=requests.get(url).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
questions =soup.find_all("ul", class_="questions")

for question in questions:
    contents = soup.find_all("li", class_="questions-content first odd")
    for content in contents:
    ques=question.find("a", class_="content_permalink").text
    print(ques)
```

How the html looks like :
[image: html]

first loop to get the ul with the class question

and then a loop to get the li inside of it

then get the content of the a

is my logic right ??

**My issue :**

```
    ques=question.find("a", class_="content_permalink").text
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue with the error adjust your indentation:

```
for content in contents:
    ques=question.find("a", class_="content_permalink").text
    print(ques)
```

instead of

```
for content in contents:
ques=question.find("a", class_="content_permalink").text
print(ques)
```

Comment: thank you this fixes the syntax error but unfortunately the code returns nothing , something is wrong